# Autoplay Video on Android

Tags: android, html, video, popup

I am currently developing an HTML kiosk presentation for iPad and Android. Issue I am having is with popup videos on Android, which works perfectly on iPad and also within Chrome on Android. I need to present this as a kiosk style application and so am using Protosee on iPad and Fully Kiosk Browser on android which I believe uses the Android Webview (Chromium) engine so should work too but doesn't.

Using FKB the video popup comes up but with a blank screen and a video icon in the centre, touching the screen again removes the popup and the video plays in the background.

Any pointers would be much appreciated.

Code is as follows

```
<html>
<head>
<title>BASE Charging Stand</title>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes"/>
<link href="logitech.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/logitech.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="main_content basechargingstand">
<div class="header">
<div class="hotspot" onclick="goBack()"></div>
<a href="index.html"><div class="hotspot"></div></a>
<a href="all_products.html"><div class="hotspot"></div></a>
</div>
<div class="page_navigation">
<div class="top_slot" onclick="goBack()"></div>
</div>
<div class="product_detail">
<div id="video_pop" onclick="onPopClick()"></div>
<a onclick="onVideoClick('videos/Base.mp4');">
<img src="images/play_btn_lrg.png" width="78"/>
</a>
<a href="base_charging_stand_detail.html"><div class="hotspot 3col"></div></a>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>

</script>
function onVideoClick(theLink) {
document.getElementById("video_pop").innerHTML = "<video poster autoplay id=\"the_Video\"><source src=\""+theLink+"\" type=\"video/mp4\" ></video>";
document.getElementById("video_pop").style.display="block";
document.getElementById('video_pop').play(); 
} 

function onPopClick() {
document.getElementById("video_pop").style.display="none";
document.getElementById("video_pop").innerHTML = ""; 
}         
</script>


<style>
#video_pop {
    z-index: 9999;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px; 
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100%; 
    background: rgb(193, 198, 201) !important; 
    display: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    top: 20.7%;
}

#the_Video {
    width: 100%;

    position: fixed;
    top: 60.5%;
    left: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);

}
</style>
```

Comment: Why do you want to make an **app**? It's a **web page**. Just make the mobile version of it. Really, there's no actual need to make an app which only links to or that mimicks a web page!!

Comment: Just to add that all of the content / videos will be stored locally on the Android device.

Comment: ... which not a good idea. Wht do you want to **spam** the user's device(s) with your favourite videos?

Comment: Because it will be used as a standalone POS display instore not a generally accessible web page.

Comment: Is it worth the candle? I mean, a double app (iOS, Android), instead of a single web page?

Comment: It is a single web page / site, just want it to work on both platforms.

Comment: That's what web sites are meant to. Provide access to **all** platforms. Not needing separate apps.

Answer (score 1):

Android and iOS have disabled video autoplay with purpose! Imagine browsing the web with your phone and all the video advertisements that could be playing in the background will just simply eat up all your bandwidth.

While working with hybrid HTML clients, I used this trick/workaround to start autoplaying videos: When user entered the page for the first time, then `<video>` element with empty src has to be created the page (hidden somewhere). Whenever user touches the screen for the first time for whatever reason, then I tried to invoke play method on the video element (this breaks the first usergesture on html video element). This will usually give a small error/warning in console but that is okay because what matters is that the first user gesture has been made, thus enabling you to use play() method whenever you want! So after the first user gesture has been made, you simply just have to use the same `<video>` element!

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you cannot Autoplay a video inside a WebView in Android. I believe Android does it for security reasons, so apps don't use too much mobile data unless the user wants it. Maybe you could try it by having the video stored locally?